# Adding classes to Joomla 3 li tag on a menu

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I'm learning Joomla and I am facing this problem:

I need to add classes to a couple of li tags generated dynamically by Joomla.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="mod-menu">
<ul class="nav menu nav-pills margin-awards">
<li class="item-207 <!--NEED TO ADD A CLASS HERE--> firstItem">
<a class="span7" target="_blank" href="sadasfasfasfasdasdasd">
<img alt="TIFF" src="/images/tsadds.png">
</a>
</li>
<li class="item-208 <!--NEED TO ADD A CLASS HERE-->">
<a class="" target="_blank" href="http://sadasdasda">
<img alt="Fantasticfest" src="/images/asdasd.png">
</a>
</li>
```

so, I can add a class to the anchor tag and the unordered list tag, but I can't find an option to add it to the list item tag.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by myself.
Using jQuery I added the classes using tags and classes to add the new class

```
<script>
jQuery( "li.item-207" ).addClass('span7');
jQuery( "li.item-208" ).addClass('span4');
jQuery( "li.item-209" ).addClass('span1');
</script>
```